# When searching anything with comma with JHipster, I am getting error in response

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, jhipster

When I am searching anything with JHipster along with a comma, it's giving an error in response. When I am removing this line then I am not getting an error but I cannot remove this line because I am using JHispter scroll pagination.

```
this.links = this.parseLinks.parse(res.headers.get('link'));
this.totalItems = res.headers.get('X-Total-Count');
```

> ```
> vendor.dll.js:1514 ERROR Error: section could not be split on ";"
> at :8080/vendor.dll.js:112091:23 [angular]
> at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) [angular]
> at ParseLinks.parse (vendor.dll.js:112088) [angular]
> at SafeSubscriber._next (stock-indent.component.ts:142) [angular]
> at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (vendor.dll.js:14697) [angular]
> at SafeSubscriber.next (vendor.dll.js:14646) [angular]
> at Subscriber._next (vendor.dll.js:14586) [angular]
> at Subscriber.next (vendor.dll.js:14550) [angular]
> at FinallySubscriber.Subscriber._next (vendor.dll.js:14586) [angular]
> at FinallySubscriber.Subscriber.next (vendor.dll.js:14550) [angular]
> at MapSubscriber._next (vendor.dll.js:30810) [angular]
> at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (vendor.dll.js:14550) [angular]
> at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (vendor.dll.js:14586) [angular]
> at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (vendor.dll.js:14550) [angular]
> ```

Comment: As you may have found ParseLinks which is used for pagination uses both comma and semi column. So it seems that this parsing should be restricted somehow. https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster/blob/master/src/service/parse-links.service.ts strange thing is that it is suposed to be in a header, so maybe you should put a breakpoint in debugger to see what is passed to this function.

Comment: Thanks Gael Marzious